# Calculate time difference between events given the distance in Python

Tags: python, time, distance, difference

I need help with a python code.
So, I have a dataset that looks something like this (for brevity only 5 places are shown here but there are more in the real dataset).

| Time of event X | Place A | Place B | Place C | Place D | Place E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08-11-2022 5:23:14 | 12 | 18 | 3.2 | 40 | 5.7 |
| 08-11-2022 6:18:14 | 5 | 9 | 2.1 | 9 | 8 |
| 08-11-2022 6:20:14 | 4 | 10 | 11 | 6.4 | 7 |
| 08-11-2022 6:22:14 | 4.6 | 12 | 9 | 5.8 | 7.2 |
| 08-11-2022 7:23:14 | 23 | 7 | 45 | 21 | 6 |
| 08-11-2022 8:23:14 | 12 | 11 | 12 | 7 | 11 |
| 08-11-2022 9:23:14 | 1.7 | 3.5 | 30 | 6 | 8.9 |

"Time" represents the time of event X, while Places A, B, C... represent the distances of manufacturing facilities (A, B, C...) from the location of event X.

I am trying to write a code in Python that will count how many times the event X happened in the next 10 minutes if it did NOT happen for at least 50 minutes, but only for those distances that are lower than 5 km.

So far I did the following:

- Subsampled only the variables that represent the distances (i.e., Places A, B, C...)

`cols = df.iloc[:, 1:24]`

- Then filtered the distance variables to those equal or lower than 5 km.

`filtered = cols[cols.iloc[:, 0:23] <= 5]`

which gave me a set with NaN values for values higher than 5km and kept the original values in place where the distances were lower than or equal to 5.

| Time of event X | Place A | Place B | Place C | Place D | Place E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08-11-2022 5:23:14 | NaN | NaN | 3.2 | NaN | NaN |
| 08-11-2022 6:18:14 | 5 | NaN | 2.1 | NaN | NaN |
| 08-11-2022 6:20:14 | 4 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 08-11-2022 6:22:14 | 4.6 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 08-11-2022 7:23:14 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 08-11-2022 8:23:14 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 08-11-2022 9:23:14 | 1.7 | 3.5 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

I then returned the Time column to the set.

Now I need to calculate how many times this event happened in the 10 minutes span if it did not occur in the last 50 minutes, for each location where this condition exists.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: show what you expect to see in the end.

Comment: @inquirer I expect to get a list that contains column names followed by the total count of occurrences in the 10 minute span for each column (if the event did not happen in the 50 minute span). If there are multiple cases where the even did not happen in the 50-minute span but it did happen in the next 10 minutes after those 50 minutes, then I expect to get those values too, separated by a comma.

Comment: 50 minutes is what to watch in the past, and 10 minutes in the future (forward), right? In those 10 minutes, you need the number of occurrences for each column (for example: Place A =3)?

Comment: you: 'but only for those distances that are lower than 5 km'. Does it mean that in this 50 minutes you need to check the values of each column for the presence of values <= 5, or does this only apply to the Time of event X column?